# Интересная фича с hover

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, button

Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы кнопка под кругом работала, так же как и над кругом ? Может будут идеи как это реализовать? 
Используя только стили, и ничего другого.

```css
.OvalMan {
  width: 136px;
  height: 136px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: var(--white);
  border: solid 5px blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.button {  
 
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.button:hover{
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.button:hover + .flex-item.OvalMan {
    box-shadow: 40px 30px 40px 40px rgb(190, 7, 7);
}
```

```html
    <input type="button" class="button " value="Тык">
    <div class="flex-item OvalMan"> </div>
    <input type="button" class="button " value="Тык">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Поместить обе кнопки перед кругом; 2) При помощи `flex` и `order` задать порядок следования второй кнопки за кругом; 3) Использовать селектор `~` .

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.OvalMan {
  width: 136px;
  height: 136px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-color: var(--white);
  border: solid 5px blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.button {   
  margin-top: 16px;
}
.button:nth-child(2){
  order:1;
}
.button:hover{
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.button:hover ~ .flex-item.OvalMan {
    box-shadow: 40px 30px 40px 40px rgb(190, 7, 7);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="button" class="button " value="Тык">
  <input type="button" class="button " value="Тык">
  <div class="flex-item OvalMan"> </div>
</div>
```